# Correct use of Prepositions

Tags: prepositions

Which of the following is grammatically correct 
a)  The documents are attached along with.
b)  The documents are attached in.
c) The documents are attached.
d) The documents are attached with.
Please first rate which of above is correct then suggest any better structure if you have.

Comment: Please include more detail to explain why this structure is confusing to you, and what research you have done to answer it.  Otherwise the question should be closed as proofreading.

Answer (score 1):

The only one that makes sense as is, is:

> The documents are attached

Assuming it's something like an email and the sender is notifying the receiver that something is attached with the mail.

The other three are basically unfinished sentences, so you would need to include what they are **in**, or what they are **with**

For example:

> The documents are attached in **this email**

Comment: Please review the site rules.  We try not to answer "proofreading" questions here, unless the question includes enough detail that the answer may be useful to someone else.  Instead this question should be closed.

Comment: Note that *attached **with** this email* and *attached **to** this email* could also be considered correct. The problem with the question is not that three of the example sentences are using incorrect prepositions, but that they are incomplete sentences. If a), b), and d) all ended with *this email*, they would all be correct.

Comment: @JasonBassford - yep I agree, I did say they were unfinished sentences as they stand.

Comment: I do agree I couldn't perceive the sense, as well. But the problem of mine being, I encountered the question as mcq, as it is,  in annual paper of mine. So I thought if someone could tell me the best among choices. Well thanks for response!